# Is there a more concise method to initialize these variables?

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, control-flow, variable-initialization

`m` is either 0, 1, 2, or 3:

```
if m==0 
    afit0=afit(1);
elseif m==1
    afit0=afit(1);
    afit1=afit(2);
elseif m==2 
    afit0=afit(1);
    afit1=afit(2);
    afit2=afit(3);
elseif m==3 
    afit0=afit(1);
    afit1=afit(2);
    afit2=afit(3);
    afit3=afit(4);
end
```

Is there a more concise way to write this code?

Comment: Is `afit` a vector or function? Do you really need to create a bunch of separate numbered variables? Using vectors is a better approach.

Comment: afit is a vector, but I need to name the individual elements of afit (they're coefficients of a polynomial).

Comment: If you explain the larger problem you're trying to solve, I'm quite certain there's a better approach.

Comment: A function computes the vector afit, which is a column vector with possible lengths 1 through m, where m is inputted by the user. I've then got to name each of the elements in afit as afit0, afit1, ... , afitm.

Comment: @beaker I tried doing:
For k=0:m
      afitk=afit(k+1)
end
however, this does not work.

Comment: Why not `a(1)`, `a(2)`, ..., `a(m)`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're referring to?

Comment: And I'm not sure why you're "renaming" the elements of the vector `afit`. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm renaming the elements of the vector from a(1),a(2),...,a(m+1) to a0, a1,...,am as the polynomial is y=a0 + a1x + a2x^2 +...+amx^m, and I need to specifically state the values of the coefficients.

Comment: You could compute your polynomial using [vectorized operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) instead: `y = sum(afit(1:(m+1)).*x.^(0:m));`

Comment: "Specifically state the values of the coefficients" Do you need to do this in the code (i.e. creating variables, which makes very little sense) or print to the screen in a user-readable format? I suspect the latter. Is this a homework exercise? If not, please describe the larger problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I suppose I could just print to the command window. This is a homework exercise. So is there a more efficient way to code this if I just print to the command window?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you find yourself breaking a vector into separate variables in MATLAB, you're *probably* making more work for yourself. MATLAB is optimized for operations involving vectors and matrices, and using [vectorization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) will often give you more efficient and concise code.

From your comments, it appears that you ultimately want to evaluate a polynomial `y = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + ... + am*x^m`, where your coefficients `a0` through `am` are the variables you are wanting to initialize from the column vector `afit`. A better alternative would be to use vectorized operations to compute your polynomial using `afit` directly:

```
y = sum(afit(1:(m+1)).*x.^(0:m).');
```

Here, we [index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/indexing.html) `afit` based on the value of `m` and then [multiply](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/times.html) the resulting sub-vector element-wise by a value `x` raised element-wise to the [power](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) given in the column vector `(0:m).'`. The resulting vector of values is them summed using [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) to get the result `y`.

[As Ben points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782030/more-concise-method-than-if-loop#comment82527363_47782772), there is even a built-in function [`polyval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) that can perform this evaluation for you. You just have to [flip](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) the order of elements in the sub-vector indexed from `afit`:

```
y = polyval(flip(afit(1:(m+1)), 1), x);
```

Comment: `polyval` does this and allows the input to be a vector of values at which to evaluate the polynomial

Comment: @BenVoigt: Good point. I wanted to focus on the vectorization aspect, but it's worth mentioning. Added!